# Virtual Machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running

Tags: windows-update, hyper-v, hypervisor, microsoft, hyper-v-manager

I've recently found host servers installing patch KB5009624 and after a reboot is unable to power on the virtual machines.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft already has released updates that patches this.

Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2: KB5010794
Windows Server 2012: KB5010797

Available for Windows Update as optional update
Windows 11, version 21H1 (original release): KB5010795
Windows Server 2022: KB5010796
Windows 10, version 21H2: KB5010793
Windows 10, version 21H1: KB5010793
Windows 10, version 20H2, Windows Server, version 20H2: KB5010793
Windows 10, version 20H1, Windows Server, version 20H1: KB5010793
Windows 10, version 1909, Windows Server, version 1909: KB5010792
Windows 10, version 1607, Windows Server 2016: KB5010790
Windows 10, version 1507: KB5010789
Windows 7 SP1: KB5010798
Windows Server 2008 SP2: KB5010799